# What is a python/pandas equivalent to R's `with`?

Tags: python, r, pandas

In R I can have a data.frame or a list with several arguments, and I can operate on them using the `with` function. For example:

```
d <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 2:4, z = 3:5)
# I can use:
d$x+d$y*d$z-5
# Or, more simply, I can use:
with(d, x+y*z-5)
# [1]  2  9 18
```

In pandas DataFrame I can use:

```
d = {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 3, 4], 'z': [3, 4, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.x+df.y*df.z-5
# 0     2
# 1     9
# 2    18
# dtype: int64
```

But is there a way to do some "with" like statement?

Comment: I don't know about R but if your intention is putting a variable in a context, no there is no way to do it in Python. There is a `with` statement but it works with objects that has special methods and it's completely different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One idea is use [`DataFrame.eval`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html) if need processing some columns names some simple arithmetic operations:

```
print (df.x+df.y*df.z-5)
0     2
1     9
2    18
dtype: int64

print (df.eval('x+y*z-5'))
0     2
1     9
2    18
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Bingo, .eval is what I wanted. Thanks!